# I created two different objects in one object. On printing them, only the last modified object is getting displayed. How to create?

Tags: javascript

```
var friends=new Object();
friends.bill=new Object();
friends.steve=new Object();
var friends={
    bill:{
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "gates",
        number:'040404040',
        address: ['bcd','sdad']
      }
};
var friends={
  steve:{
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number:'131313131',
        address:['abc','sdsdsd']
      }
};
console.log(friends);
```

the output of this program is all about the object "steve". If I log "friends.steve" it logs as "undefined". I want the output to be two diffrent objects in the object friend.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the previously create object.

Rather you should try

```
var friends=new Object();
friends.bill=new Object();
friends.steve=new Object();
friends.bill={
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "gates",
        number:'040404040',
        address: ['bcd','sdad']
};
friends.steve={
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number:'131313131',
        address:['abc','sdsdsd']
      };
console.log(friends);
```

Answer (score 1):

To store **multiple values** in a variable you can use the **Array**.

```
var bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "gates",
    number:'040404040',
    address: ['bcd','sdad']
}

var steve = {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number:'131313131',
        address:['abc','sdsdsd']
}

var friends = [bill, steve];
console.log(friends);
```

Also, in your code, you are defining the variable **friends**, which overwrite the variable defined with the same name. Additionally, you can define the class for friend and can create 2 objects from the class.

```
function Friend(firstname, lastname, number, address)
{
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.number = number;
    this.address = address;
}

var bill = new Friend("Bill", "gates", "address", 040404040  ,['bcd','sdad']);
var steve = new Friend("Steve", "Jobs", "address",  131313131,  ['abc','sdsdsd']); 
var friends = [bill, steve];
console.log(friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you define friends variable and override again in next few lines

```
'var friends={
    bill:{'
```

This will override the first object and new instance will taking place instead.

Try this code and this will solve your problem

```
var friends = new Object();

    friends.bill = {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "gates",
        number:'040404040',
        address: ['bcd','sdad']
    };

    friends.steve ={
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number:'131313131',
        address:['abc','sdsdsd']
    };

    console.log(friends);
```

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, it has no explanation as to why. Code on its own is seldom sufficient. Please add an explanation so that the OP and others can understand why your code is better, and what was wrong in the code shown in the question.